# How to reconstruct another component from a function in another component in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is going to sound confusing but i have 3 components here.
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwDA2.jpg)

Now ticket-projects-new component is the first to build and data is fetched from db to this component. Then data is passed from ticket-projects-new to crupdate-ticket-project-model in the ts file. Then the same data is passed from permissionProject-manager component through html file. Now this is a function in the crupdate-ticket-project-model component.

```
public close() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

here i set it to reload page because it will refetch data however, is there any way to do this like make the ticket-projects-new component to refetch the data again or rebuild component without reloading the page?

Comment: Can you please add more code? How do you fetch data in the first place? How do you pass it to other components?

Answer (score 0):

In the crupdate-ticket-project-model component:

```
public refreshEvent: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

public close() {
    this.refreshEvent.emit();
}
```

This emits an event which we can listen for in the ticket-projects-new component.
In the ticket-projects-new component html where you initialise the crupdate-ticket-project-model component:

```
<crupdate-ticket-project-model (refreshEvent)="refreshMethod($event)" ></crupdate-ticket-project-model>
```

In the ticket-projects-new component ts create the refreshMethod() that will call the refresh code you call when the component loads eg:

```
refreshMethod(event: Event){
  <WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_REFRESH>
}
```